# Failed loading plugin "subscription-manager" : No module named 'decorator'

Tags: linux

Error: If you get the this error when you run the dnf/yum command

```
Failed loading plugin "subscription-manager": No module named 'decorator'
Failed loading plugin "product-id": No module named 'decorator'
Failed loading plugin "upload-profile": No module named 'decorator'
```

Comment: Please don't provide the solution in the answer, instead post it as an answer and accept it. Otherwise the question will stay as a"unsolved" in the system forever. It is perfectly fine to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Install this package to resolve the above decorator error.

```
yum install python3-decorator -y
```